# Existence of a honeycomb composed by nearly-hyperspherical $d$-dimensional cells having the same shape and size

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, combinatorial-optimization, packing-and-covering

Let $\mathcal{H}$ the class of all honeycombs composed by $d$-dimensional cells $C$ having all the same shape and size in a $d$-dimensional space $\mathcal{S}$.
Let $s(C)$ and $\ell(C)$ be respectively the length of the smallest and largest segment obtained through an orthogonal projection of $C$ onto a straight line over all straight lines in $\mathcal{S}$. Finally, for any given $h\in\mathcal{H}$, let $b(h)$ be equal to $\frac{\ell(C)}{s(C)}$ (informally, we view $b(h)$ as a measure providing information about to what extent the cells $C$ of $h$ are similar to a $d$-dimensional ball).

---

***Example:*** For d=2 we have if we consider the hexagonal tiling $h\in\mathcal{H}$, $C$ is the hexagon, the radius of the circumscribed circle is equal to $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ times the apothem. Hence, it is immediate to verify that we have $b(h)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. For $d=3$, we could consider the honeycomb $h\in\mathcal{H}$ made up of truncated octahedrons and calculate $b(h)$. Finally, in general, if we consider $d$-dimensional hypercubic honeycomb $h\in\mathcal{H}$, we have $b(h)=\sqrt{d}$, showing that this honeycomb is far from being composed by nearly-hyperspherical $d$-dimensional cells.

---

---

**Question:** How can we prove or disprove the following conjecture?

There exists a constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$ (that does *not* depend on $d$) such that, for all $d>1$, we have a $d$-dimensional honeycomb $h\in\mathcal{H}$ for which $b(h)\le c$.

Comment: "For any $d>1$ there exists a constant $c\in\mathbb R$" Are you sure that you wanted this order of quantifiers and not the reverse one (i.e., that $c$ is allowed to depend on $d$)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @fedja. I rephrased the question. By the way, $c$ does not depend on $d$. Looking at the cases when $d$ is small I feel that $b(C)$ might be upper bounded by a constant (that does not depend on $d$) for all $d$. However it is not clear whether there is a "hidden" dependence on $d$ which is significant in higher dimensions.

Comment: Anyway if such $c$ does not exist, it would be very interesting to know how it depends on $d$.

Comment: Apparently Rogers showed back in 1950 that every packing lattice for a unit ball is contained in a 3-covering packing lattice (i.e., the new lattice is still packing but if you extend the balls 3 times, then they will cover the entire space). This would give the estimate $c\le 3$ (just consider the Voronoi cells for that lattice). The standard reference is  C. A. Rogers. A note on coverings and packings.J. London Math. Soc., 25:327–331, 1950 but I could not check it myself because it is behind a paywall.

Comment: Thank you a lot @fedja!

Comment: Permutohedra would be a good case to investigate here (generalizing hexagons and truncated octahedra) but I couldn't easily find the ratio of in/circumradii anywhere obvious and was too lazy to compute it. Exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you very much @SteveHuntsman. By the way, what fedja said already confirms that the conjecture is true as far as I understood (I did not have yet the time to check the reference he provided me), right?

Comment: To add to Fedja's comment, the problem of finding a lattice with the smallest possible ratio of covering radius to packing radius is also the subject of a paper of Schurmann and Vallentin (arxiv.org/abs/math/0403272), where they cite a result of Butler for the statement that the optimal ratio is asymptotically 2+o(1)

Comment: Thank you a lot @YoavKallus!

Comment: Butler's result is an upper bound, that the packing-covering ratio is $\leq 2 + o(1)$. I don't think that an analogous lower bound has been established.

Comment: Thank you @AdamP.Goucher. I was interested in an upper bound of $b(h)$ to answer to my question. By the way I think a lower bound would be interesting on its own.